# Crc error with Expansion files

Tags: android, zip, crc, expansion

Got success in uploading and download the Expansion files [Apk external data, Android Expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10327532/apk-external-data-android-expansion)

but now I am facing *CRC* while unzipping my files.

Not getting exactly where the problem is, Google rename my files as `.obb`

Searching for workaround, if any?

**Update**

Complete explanation defined here [Steps to create APK expansion file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715855/steps-to-create-apk-expansion-file/11717019#11717019)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it, I just skip checking CRC32 algorithm and its working very fine.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info :) is that possible to tell where exactly we have to skip checking CRC32 algorithm? or explain bit more..

Comment: see In doInBackGround() you will find `if (-1 != entry.mCRC32)`, just remove it.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply @hotveryspicy :)  I quickly fixed like you said  "xapk File validation failed"  for screen shot I uploaded five screen shot on g-code bug report http://goo.gl/6pjrk..  "xapk File validation failed" comes for crc error?? sorry man I'm a beginner :(

Comment: please answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723814/xapk-file-validation-failed-in-sample-code-of-android-apk-expansion-files

Comment: It appears that CRC check fails when you use compression on your Zip file. You can use 7-Zip manager and set _Compression Level_ to _Store_ and CRC check will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are having the same problem as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928334/android-apk-expansion-files-gives-crc-error-after-downloading-file). In brief, the sample code doesn't work for compressed zip files.