# XAPK File validation shows in correct data Information

Tags: android, zip, crc, crc32

While running APK expansion file sample I just skiped checking  CRC32 to avoide crc bug algorithm and its working very fine!! But while XAPK File validation shows in correct downloaded data information 99% !!, how to avoid that and view full 100% by hard-coding?

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ZalaJanaksinh  answered my own question! try with that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a best sloution but I got the solution by hard coding the
 `ProgressBar mPB; TextView mProgressPercent; TextView mProgressFraction;` in DownloaderActivity onPostExecute method of validationAsynctask

```
    mPB.setMax(10);
    mPB.setProgress(100);
    mProgressPercent.setText(100 + "%");
    mProgressFraction.setText("Download Completed Successfully");
```